# Testing the randomness of a character string

Tags: random, encryption

I have a cipher I've been toying around with that mimics a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). I'd like to run tests on the keys I generate to see where they lie on the scale of random to pseudo-random. I've found a number of test suites that work on binary strings, but none that work on character strings. Are there any test suites that will work on character strings (or integer strings)? If not, what would be the correct way to convert the character string to a binary string?

Answer (score 1):

A character string IS a binary string.  The only thing is that, if you limit it to certain "printable" characters, there are some bit patterns that are never used.

Eg, if you limit the string to the characters `A...Z` then only 26 of 256 possible 8-bit values are used.  So one can, in theory, map `A...Z` to `0,1...24,25` and then compute `charIndex[0] + charIndex[1] * 26 + charIndex[2] * 26 * 26 ...` to get the "unbiased" numeric value of the entire string.  This, of course, isn't practical, but perhaps it gives you an idea.

Less complex is to simply consider the relative likelihood of individual characters.  Ie, all characters of your "alphabet" should occur with equal frequency, and, given that, eg, the string "KFUTRP" has occurred, all characters of your alphabet should be equally likely as the next character.

Perhaps more complicated but less restrictive is to allow characters to have different frequencies, but still have "KFUTRP" not "predict" any character with greater/less likelihood than its overall frequency.

Ultimately it`s about the ability of a sequence of characters to "predict" the next character in the sequence.

But, if this is for a one-time-pad, the thing to do is to run your character string through some sort of hash that resembles a cryptographic hash, and use the hashed value as your one-time pad.  Then even if the character string is recognizable text the hash value would be random.  All you'd really want/need to do then is to test the resulting hash value for randomness.